# Stereographic projection maps lines and circles on the plane into circles in the sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, analytic-geometry, stereographic-projections

From pages $19$ and $20$ of Ahlfors' *Complex Analysis*:

[image]

[image]

---

**Why is the converse true? Why does *any* line or circle in the plane mapped into a circle in the sphere?**